# Trying to use setTimeout inside setInterval - Open to suggestions for alternatives

Tags: javascript, settimeout, setinterval

I have a never ending loop through setInterval that works perfectly.  A simple example:

```
        setInterval(() => {
            
          axios.request(getPresence).then(function (response) {
              console.clear()
              var statusDND = 0
              var statusOffline = 0
              var statusOnline = 0
              var allStatus = []
              for (var j in response.data.items) {
                  allStatus.push({status: response.data.items[j].appearance})
              }
              for (var k in allStatus){
                  if (allStatus[k].status == 'ONLINE'){
                      statusOnline = statusOnline + 1
                  }else if(allStatus[k].status == 'OFFLINE'){
                      statusOffline = statusOffline + 1
                  }else{
                      statusDND = statusDND + 1
                  }
              }
              console.log ("Online: " + statusOnline + "\n" + "Offline: " + statusOffline + "\n" + "DoNotDisturb: " + statusDND)

              if (statusOnline < 11){
                  setTimeout(function(){
                                  console.log("Hello World");
                  console.log('\u0007');
                          }, 7000);

              }

          }).catch(function (error) {
          console.error(error);
          });
    
        }, 2000)
```

This works the very first run through but then just fires instantly and I know why after digging through how setTimeout works a bit.

I'm open to any solution that will have the code continue to loop through, checking the API, if statusOnline is less than 11, I want it to log "Hello world" or anything else to the console and then continue to log to the console every 1 minute until the statusOnline goes back above 10.  So I want the whole setInterval loop continuing to do it's thing over and over again (I need it to keep generating the counts because I pull data from there in another place).  If I remove the setTimeout, it works of course but sends the hello world to console every run through, which is too frequent.

I'm going to stop there so I don't just repeat myself over and over.

I've tried a ton of if then logic with timestamps different ways but I can't think of another way to do this without branching the whole thing and repeating the entire api request which I don't want to do, mostly because it would then be on the new 1 minute timer and updating the status values too infrequently.

I've banged my head on this for too long now.

Hope I typed things up ok, it's my first time posting on SO.  Usually I can find what I need from Google-Fu...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can start and stop another interval instead of a timeout. You would need to keep track of it outside the first interval:

```js
let noficiationIntervalId = null
setInterval(async () => {
  const response = await axios.request(getPresence)
  ...
  if (statusOnline < 11 && !noficiationIntervalId){
    noficiationIntervalId = setInterval(...)     
  } else if(statusOnline >= 11 && noficiationIntervalId){
    clearInterval(noficiationIntervalId)
    noficiationIntervalId = null
  }
```